# multiple filters vs OR , ndb query

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

What is the difference between these queries:

1. With consequent filters:

   ```
   qry1 = Account.query() # Retrieve all Account entitites
   qry2 = qry1.filter(Account.userid >= 40) # Filter on userid >= 40
   qry3 = qry2.filter(Account.userid < 50) # Filter on userid < 50 as well
   ```
2. Using ndb.OR:

   ```
   qry = Article.query(ndb.OR(Account.userid >= 40,
                          Account.userid < 50))
   ```
3. Using ndb.AND:

   ```
   qry = Article.query(ndb.AND(Account.userid >= 40,
                           Account.userid < 50))
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query does an AND. Thus, only the entities that match both inequalities will be returned by the query. The second query does an OR. Thus, entities that match either of the filters will be returned. For more information about ndb queries, take a look at [NDB Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries).

Comment: thank you for your response, if I change ndb.OR with ndb.AND, is there any differences ? I edit the questino

Comment: The third query (ndb.AND) does exactly the same thing as the first query, that is only the entities that match both inequalities will be returned by the query.

Comment: could you help me in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454457/how-to-register-google-app-engine-to-xmpp-client

Answer (score 2):

Third and the First query are exactly identical. But the second query is absurd, it may end up returning all *Entities* in the *Kind*.

Comment: THANK your for your response ! could you please help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454457/how-to-register-google-app-engine-to-xmpp-client