# How to use cursor with google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I got this error:`cursor argument should be str or unicode (0)`
when running this python code :

```
#get cursor
        curs = self.request.get('cursor',0)
        cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=curs)
        #get messages
        messages, next_curs, more = Message().queryMessages(userId=945454,bussId=454545,cursor=cursor)
```

the error pointing to `cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=curs)`

what's the problem ?

Comment: what value does cursor have? Tried logging that value to debug log perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set a default for `cursor` of 0. So, if it's not in the request, that is the value that will be used as the argument to instantiate a new cursor. Obviously, that's not a valid value.

Instead, don't set a default, and only instantiate a cursor if you get a value in the request:

```
cursor = None
curs = self.request.get('cursor')
if curs:
    cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=curs)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, could you please help me in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438435/multiple-filters-vs-or-ndb-query