# How to register google app engine to xmpp client?

Tags: python, xmpp, google-app-engine

I am using [psi](http://psi-im.org/download/) to test the xmpp service in my app engine project.
when I open psi, it asks me to enter the name of the server I wish to register with.
I tried `my_app_id.appspotchat.com` but I got "There was an error communicating with the XMPP server"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The server is `talk.google.com`. And you have to connect to it through port 5222.

Your App Engine application will act just as an endpoint for XMPP packets, i.e. to send/receive presence and message packets, not as a server itself.

Comment: thank you for your response, now I am receiving this error =>Stream Negotiation Error: Host unknown !

Comment: thank you for your response, now I am receiving this error =>Stream Negotiation Error: Host unknown ,Set the 'to' attribute of stream element to the domain part of the user's JID. Example: to='gmail.com'

Comment: Which host is unknown?

Comment: I edit the question , the screen shot shows the error !